# React-boilerplate + react-toolbox: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./style

Tags: reactjs, webpack, styles, react-redux, react-toolbox

I'm using [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate) as base to my project, since it have support do Redux.

When I access my app I get the following error in the terminal:

```
ERROR in ./~/react-toolbox/lib/button/Button.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './style' in 'E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\react-toolbox\lib\button'
 @ ./~/react-toolbox/lib/button/Button.js 28:13-31

ERROR in ./~/react-toolbox/lib/button/IconButton.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './style' in 'E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\react-toolbox\lib\button'
 @ ./~/react-toolbox/lib/button/IconButton.js 28:13-31

ERROR in ./~/react-toolbox/lib/ripple/Ripple.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './style' in 'E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\react-toolbox\lib\ripple'
 @ ./~/react-toolbox/lib/ripple/Ripple.js 23:13-31
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
         Asset     Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
    index.html  20.5 kB       0
    chunk    {0} index.html 1.03 kB [rendered]
        [0] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./app/index.html 1.03 kB {0} [built]
Error: no such file or directory
    at MemoryFileSystem.readFileSync (E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\node_modules\memory-fs\lib\MemoryFileSystem.js:107:10)
    at app.get (E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\server\middlewares\frontendMiddleware.js:25:21)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
    at param (E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:349:14)
    at param (E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
    at next (E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
    at middleware (E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\webpack-hot-middleware\middleware.js:39:48)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
    at E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (E:\ReactLaravel\Boilerplate\react-boilerplate-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
```

My App/containers/MyContainer/index.js which is the main entry for this part of the application:
https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/files/285221/index.zip

My package.json:
https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/files/285226/package.json.zip

The file I believe is the equivalent to webpack.config.js in this boilerplate template:
https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/files/285227/webpack.test.babel.zip

How cold I solve this error and using react-toolbox together react-boilerplate?

Comment: Could you paste your webpack config file?

Comment: As I said above, this boilerplate template have no webpack.config file, with exception of those inside "node_modules\redux-saga\": webpack.config.base.js, webpack.config.dev.js and webpack.config.prod.js.

Comment: react-boilerplate seems not support sass.